# Using grid view in iOS with pinch to zoom

Tags: xcode, zooming, pinch, aqgridview

I am creating an application that will load images in a grid format. The user will be able to see a grid of images and pinch to zoom in the image area.

I have looked at AQGridView but I am unsure as to whether or not it supports pinch to zoom.